# How to import GEO_TYPE from file in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Creating index using below query. Elastic Search is running on windows.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/us_large_cities -d  "{"""mappings""": {"""city""": {"""properties""": {"""city""": {"""type""": """string"""},"""state""": {"""type""": """string"""},"""location""": {"""type""": """geo_point"""}}}}}"
```

Creating document using below command.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/us_large_cities/city/ -d "{"""city""": """Birmingham""", """state""": """AL""","""location""": {"""lat""": """33.5206608""", """lon""": """-86.8024900"""}}"
```

Everything is running fine using command. But when i want to import data using json file using below query.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/us_large_cities/city/_bulk?pretty --data-binary "@citylocation.txt"
```

Its giving me error.

'Error type : Illegal_argumaent_exception'

'Reason : malformed action/metadata line[1] , expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but foung [VALUE STRING]

My file data is :

{"city": "Birmingham", "state": "AL","location": {"lat" : "33.5206608", "long" : "-86.8024900"}}

{"city": "Huntsville", "state": "AL","location": {"lat" : "34.7303688", "long" : "-86.5861037"}}

{"city": "Mobile", "state": "AL","location": {"lat" : "30.6943566", "long" : "-88.0430541"}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the meta data field and then the data field.
Ideally you text file should hold data in following format

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "us_large_cities", "_type" : "city" } }
{"city": "Birmingham", "state": "AL","location": {"lat" : 33.5206608, "long" : -86.8024900}}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "us_large_cities", "_type" : "city" } }
{"city": "Mobile", "state": "AL","location": {"lat" : 30.6943566, "long" : -88.0430541}}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, now its giving me error 'Filed must be either [lat] , [long] or [geohash]'..

Comment: When i am using below format it inserted the value successfully. { "index" : { "_index" : "us_large_cities", "_type" : "city" } }
{"city": "Birmingham", "state": "AL","location": [33.5206608,-86.8024900]}  { "index" : { "_index" : "us_large_cities", "_type" : "city" } }
{"city": "Mobile", "state": "AL","location": [30.6943566,-88.0430541]}                                                                                                              Want to know whats wrong with the your solution why its give us exception..

Comment: lat and long were given as string in the sample you gave me. It should be as long.